# How to create API to consume SAP B1 Service Layer in SAP BTP using Integration Suite

Tags: service-layer, sap-business-technology-platform, sap-business-one-di-api, sap-cpi, sap-btp-sdk-ios

I have created a destination on my SAP BTP account.

To consume the SAP Business One Service Layer, I need to create an API where I will route to my destination.

Any help Please?

I have to create APIs to consume The SAP Business One Service Layer